# Howto capture 2 output values and process them

Tags: shell-script, disk-image

I am trying to create a fool proof solution to write an image to a memory card with help of dd.

Idea: I want to place a script on the system which others can execute with none knowledge about writing images.

The image may change in size so a query must run upfront to determine the size.

```
isoinfo -d -i /media/usb/image.iso | grep -i -E 'block size|volume size' | sed 's/^.*is: \(.*\)/\1/'
```

to get the numbers of block and volume size.
Now I need to incorporate the values into the following code

```
dd if=/media/usb/image.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=2048 count=96053 status=progress
```

I have tried to solve this by autofill bs= and count= but I cannot figure out how to grab and process the output from the first piece of code.

I tried xargs but this did not help me much. I hope you have some some solution for me.

Cheers
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set `bs` and `count` to specific values if you want to copy the whole image to the destination. Just make sure the blocksize is chosen large enough to ensure a fast copy operation like `bs=16M`. Without `count` the whole input is copied, e.g.

```
dd if=/media/usb/image.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=16M status=progress
```

Comment: Ah, wasnt aware of that behaviour.

Cheers mate :)